# Acessar variável/parâmetro de uma função dentro de outra função

Tags: javascript, funções, escopo-de-variáveis

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
 function criarDataset(field, constraint, sorFields)
 {
    totalTarefasAtrasadas = buscarTarefasAtrasadas();

    function buscarTarefasAtrasadas()
    {
       usuario = constraints[0].finalValue;
       return = 6;
    }
}
```

A variável usuario consegue receber o valor do parâmetro `constraints` da função principal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depois da edição da pergunta que o Bacco fez é que eu percebi que eu havia entendido errado. Eu fui no título e não vi que uma função está dentro da outra, até porque a indentação não sem padrão. Neste caso não precisa fazer nada, é só acessar a variável, o código já pergunta já funcionaria sem alterações, bastaria testar. Uma função interna acessa todas variáveis do escopo mais externo, então `buscarTarefasAtrasadas()` "enxerga" as variáveis de `buscarTarefasAtrasadas()`.

```js
 function criarDataset(field, constraint, sorFields) {
    totalTarefasAtrasadas = buscarTarefasAtrasadas();
    function buscarTarefasAtrasadas() {
        usuario = constraint;
        console.log(usuario);
        return 6;
    }
}

criarDataset("a", "b", "c");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/AccessParameter.js).

Agora, se o problema for ter duas funções separadas consegue também, é só passar ela como parâmetro para a outra função. Funções sempre devem se comunicar através de parâmetros e retorno.

```js
 function criarDataset(field, constraint, sorFields) {
     totalTarefasAtrasadas = buscarTarefasAtrasadas(constraint);
}

function buscarTarefasAtrasadas(constraint) {
    usuario = constraint;
    console.log(usuario);
    return 6;
}

criarDataset("a", "b", "c");
```

Tem outras formas de resolver este caso, mas é gambiarra e não vou passar.

Answer (score 2):

Existem casos em que é necessário acessar o escopo de funções internas dentro de [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). E isso é uma possibilidade que o javascript permite, por não possuir escopo fechado. Mas é bom tomar cuidado pois a variável é utilizada como referência e não por valor. Logo, quaisquer alterações posteriores à sua chamada podem afetar o resultado da sua função.

Caso você queira/precise, uma possível solução seria:

```
function criarDataset(field, constraint, sorFields) {
  var totalTarefasAtrasadas = buscarTarefasAtrasadas();
  function buscarTarefasAtrasadas()
  {
    var usuario = constraint[0].finalValue;
    return 6;
  }
}
```

O que em alguns casos pode não ser uma gambiarra. 
  Caso você tenha alguma dúvida pode procurar mais sobre : Hoisting, Closure em javascript.